# Question on entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can I find non-constant entire functions $f$ and $g$, and complex numbers $a$ and $b$, such that, for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$
  ze^{f(z)}=e^{g(z)}+az+b
$$

I think it is not possible, but I could not prove it or disprove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $b \ne 0$ (taking $z=0$).

Write the equation as

$$G(z) = \frac{z e^{f(z)}}{a z + b} = \frac{e^{g(z)}}{a z + b} + 1 $$

where $G$ is a meromorphic function (analytic except at $z=-b/a$ if $a \ne 0$, entire if $a = 0$).

Now $G$ must have an essential singularity at $\infty$.
But the left side takes the value $0$ only at $z=0$, while the right side never takes the value $1$.  This contradicts the (great) Picard theorem.

Comment: I think there's something missing here about how $f$ entire and nonconstant implies that the power series expansion of $e^f$ has nonzero coefficients of arbitrarily high order. Otherwise, a great answer!

Comment: Might be missing something, but how does this contradict the (Great) Picard? Since $G$ is meromorphic, it is allowed to take two values finitely many times...

Comment: In a neighbourhood of $\infty$, $G$ is analytic, and Great Picard says it is only allowed to take one value finitely many times.

Comment: @RobertIsrael In truth, isn't the version for Riemann surfaces that $f$ is allowed to not take *two* values infinitely often? The obvious surface here being the Riemann sphere.

Comment: $f$ can't have a removable singularity at $\infty$, because of Liouville.  If $f$ had a pole or essential singularity at $\infty$, for any $n$ it would take values with real part in $(-\infty,-n)$ and values with real part in $(n,\infty)$  for $|z|$  arbitrarily large, implying $e^f$ has an essential singularity.

Comment: If you want to count it that way, the three values it doesn't take infinitely often are $0$, $1$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you.